# How to change buffered image and graphics in android?

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap, bufferedimage

I would need to change the Java code to Android.

I'm having the Java code with `BufferedImage` and `Graphics`.  How should I change the following Java code to Android.

My code is,

```
public static BufferedImage buff(BufferedImage bi){
    if (isGray(bi)){
        return bi;
    }
    BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), 10);
    Graphics gr = gray.getGraphics();
    gr.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    gr.dispose();
    return gray;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a bitmap that you are trying to return??

Answer (score 0):

javax.imageio isn't in the Android SDK, but the Bitmap class can be used, if you want convert to gray, you can use this:

> ```
> public static Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bm) {
>     Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
>
>     Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
>     Paint paint = new Paint();
>
>     ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
>     cm.setSaturation(0);
>     ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
>     paint.setColorFilter(f);
>
>     c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
>     return bmpGrayscale;
> }
> ```